# Change header.php after ajax call

Tags: ajax, headers

Is possible change class to body_class() after ajax call to load posts/pages?
I would say no, but I have not used much with wordpress ajax, so I ask the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to change the body class (either add class or remove class) with jQuery after the ajax call as a callback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourloop.php",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  $(this).addClass("finished-loop");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks, but the problem is detect type the posts/pages without many lines the code. If not myself clear. Sorry but my english!

Comment: Do you have the code for your ajax call?

Comment: No, sorry. I have a test but does not work 100%. So I decided to ask this question because I need the classes so that the design works well.